# PHP как отследить ошибки на сервере при запросе с другого сервера

Tags: php, сервер

Есть свой сервер ( *сервер**1*** ) с php.

Есть сторонний сервер ( *сервер**2*** ), который шлет запросы на *сервер**1***.

Код на *сервере**1*** постоянно дорабатывается/расширяется ручками.  Всякие ошибки/ляпы типо не закрытой скобки, лишней запятой.... бывают частенько.  При выполнении через браузер php выдает эти ошибки в браузер штатными средствами - все прекрасно/понятно где ляп сидит.

Как отловить те-же ошибки/ляпы при запросе сервера к серверу? Как можно получить/увидеть эти ошибки?

Comment: сервер же что-то возвращает..... и вернёт он эти ошибки при запросе к нему.........так что вопрос не ясен, в чём проблема.......

Comment: сервер1  куда вернет / запишет свои ошибки при запросе от сервера2 ??

Comment: А куда он возвращает ошибки при запросе от браузера? в поток вывода.....

Comment: Есть вариант ещё проще: скачать/купить нормальную IDE и не париться насчёт "незакрытой скобки"

Comment: Серверу 1 вообще плевать кто к нему обращается. Он просто отдаёт ответ в виде правильной информации или ошибок.... А кто обращается - ему плевать.... Так что он в любом случае отдаёт эту информацию....... Так что проблема всё ещё не ясна. В чём проблема получения этих данных.....

Comment: Куда копать - понял, Спасибо Алексею Шиманскому  за подсказку